# Why doesn't my USB Ethernet card ASIX by V.TOP give me 1 Gbps?

Tags: ethernet, usb-3, gigabit-ethernet

My router (Technicolor DGA2232) supports 1 Gbps LAN. I've confirmed this by being able to connect to it via WiFi in speeds close to that.

However, when using V.TOP INDUSTRY LIMITED's 3 Ports USB 3.0, which installs a driver called [ASIX AX88179](https://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131%3B71%3B112) (USB3.0 to 10/100/1000M Gigabit Ethernet Controller), using ASIX' latest drivers for Windows 10 64-bit, I can't get past 100 Mbps. Is there a way to fix that?

I've tried [both Cat5 and Cat6](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/cabling-utp-fibre/112-network-cabling-utp.html) cables. The Cat6 cable gave me 1 Gbps in another combination of computer/network card/router.

[image: V.TOP adapter]

[image: Ethernet card's potential speed]

[image: Ethernet card's status]

Changing **Auto Negotiation** to **1.0 Gbps Full Duplex** got the connection disconnected:
[image: Ethernet card's manual speed setting]

I've confirmed with the freeware [UsbTreeView](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html) that I'm indeed using USB 3.0:

[image: Ethernet via USB]

The router sees this:
[image: Router's ports]

The Internet's speed (as seen by the computer using Asix) is:
[image: Internet speed]

Comment: Try plugging the adapter in to another Gigabit NIC, such as another computer, then also try connecting the router to a different Gigabit NIC. See which of those fails to negotiate Gigabit speeds, just to be completely sure the problem is with your USB Ethernet NIC.

Comment: This computer has just 1 USB 3.0 port so the adapter must be connected to that port. The router is connected to the adapter so I'm not sure what you mean. I've tried all of the router's four ports if that's what you meant.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your USB ports. There is most likely a hardware problem with the Ethernet side of the USB-to-Ethernet adapter but you should confirm that the LAN ports are working normally by plugging one of them into a different device. The problem here is at least 95% likely to be your USB-to-Ethernet adapter but it's worth ruling out the router's LAN ports by connecting them to a different network device (which also supports Gigabit) and confirming that it negotiates a Gigabit connection and not 100 Mbps. You basically want to make zero assumptions!

Comment: The problem is most likely that one of the eight pins on the USB-to-Ethernet adapter has no connectivity, which would cause it to fall back from Gigabit to 100 Mbps maximum speeds. You just want to quickly test both devices against a third Gigabit device to be sure.

Comment: Makes lots of sense, but I have no other Ethernet device. Everything today uses WiFi. That's why I bought this adapter in the first place...I need to find a whole other computer and it's not straightforward to do so. And obviously I can't take the router to another place as it's meant for one place.

Comment: No problem. You can work around that. What happens if you connect any two LAN ports on the router together for a few seconds? Do their status LEDs indicate Gigabit or 100 Mbps speeds? Typically, green indicates Gigabit, while yellow or orange means 100 Mbps.

Comment: I've connected 2 of the router's 4 ports into each other. You can see it [here](https://ibb.co/jZh3vMv) (the two yellow cables). It cut off the connection and it only got back when I disconnected those cables. The LED was green but it doesn't tell me if it's 100 Mbps or Gigabit.

Comment: It might tell you something. Do you get a yellow LED instead when you connect the router to the USB-to-Ethernet adapter? Your router may not necessarily even have a different color LED for slower speeds but it's worth trying quickly. Did you buy the USB-to-Ethernet adapter recently? I would try to swap it out at the store if possible as it appears to be defective; you should be getting Gigabit speeds right out the gate with it, with no need for driver updates or troubleshooting.

Comment: You can see the lights in the previous comment's screenshot. The left cable is for the adapter while the yellow ones are for the experiment. Those lights all look identical green to me. The adapter is from eBay from 2 years ago ([see here](https://ibb.co/9V2mFxN)). But until now it wasn't tested for 1G. It seems to work fine other than that.

Comment: The router only has green status LEDs but I noticed the web interface shows what speed each LAN port is connecting at. At this point, I think one of the eight pins that is supposed to be making contact with the network cable isn't, for some reason, rendering the USB-to-Ethernet adapter unable to operate at Gigabit. Most likely, it's an internal connectivity problem inside your adapter, where you won't be able to fix it, but take a look inside its Ethernet port and make sure none of the pins are dirty or bent. Unless it's a problem with the visible pins, then I think this isn't fixable.

Comment: To clarify, when I say the problem is with one of the eight pins, I'm using that as a catch-all term to describe not only the pins themselves but also the internal wiring in the USB adapter that the pins communicate through. A loose connection somewhere inside the adapter could effectively "disconnect" a pin and downgrade the adapter to 100 Mbps. If it can't use all 8 pins (Gigabit) because of even just one faulty one, then it will fall back to just using 4 of them (100 Mbps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just hooked up [an alternative card by Unitek](https://www.unitek-products.com/products/usb-3-0-3-port-hub-gigabit-ethernet-converter) into the same computer and router. I didn't even have to install anything (although it only worked after 2 reboots for some reason), and it instantly gave me 1GB!

Therefore @mr-ethernet's comments seem to be correct - V.TOP's adapter must have had a hardware issue.

Alternative stats:

[image: Ethernet 1GB]

[image: Internet Speed]

[image: Router's ports]